# How to solve list index out of range error ? (I'm sorry if its not a good question here but I cant find any answers)

Tags: python, list

Here is the error I m getting

```
     word[i] += len(words)
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

and here is the code

```
word=[]
i=1
with open("poem.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words=line.split()
        word[i] += len(words)
        i += 1

for i in range(1,20):
    print("For the line "+i+" we have "+word[i]+" words")
```

What I want to have as an output is something like

For the line 1 we have 10 words

For the line 2 we have 20 words

and so on ...

Comment: `word.append(len(words)` also index starts from 0 not from 1

Comment: This has to be a duplicate. Indexing begins at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with how you're accessing the array. There's a better approach:

```
word=[]
with open("poem.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words=line.split()
        word.append(len(words))

for idx, count in enumerate(word):
    print("For the line " + (idx + 1) + " we have " + count + " words")
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, please accept the answer.

Comment: I will as soon as it will let me to

Comment: `word = [len(line.split()) for line in f]` in one line

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I saw that as well, but I thought the smaller iteration might be more level appropriate

Comment: Thank you, but for me its easier to understand what it does if its more in detail @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 0):

the first time the code run word will have 0 elements, but i is 1 and therefore there is no item at position 1.

Try to start with i=0

```
word=[]
i=0
```